# Proving graph theory using induction

Tags: graph-theory, induction

How would I go about proving that a graph with no cycles and n-1 edges (where n would be the number of vertices) is a tree?

I am just really confused about where to start.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First check for $n=1$, $n=2$. These are trivial. Assume it is true for $n = m$. Now consider $n=m+1$. The graph has $m+1$ vertices with $m$ edges and no cycles. Now by handshake lemma, there exists at least $2$ vertices with degree $1$. Pick on such vertex and remove it from the graph. Now you have graph on $m$ vertices with $m-1$ edges, which is a tree by induction assumption. Now complete.

Comment: How does the handshake lemma imply the existence of 2 vertices with degree 1? I think I have a proof without the handshake lemma, but I do not see how you use it.

Comment: @babou We have $\sum_{k=1}^n d_k = 2\vert E \vert = 2(n-1)$. Now no vertex had a degree $1$, then $\sum_{k=1}^n d_k \geq 2n$. Similarly, if only one vertex had degree $1$, then $\sum_{k=1}^n d_k \geq 2n-1$.

Comment: But you could have vertices with degree 0. Connectedness is not an hypothesis.

Comment: If it is not connected, then split it into two connected components with $a$ and $b$ vertices. Then either the first one has at least $a$ edges or second one has at least $b$ edges and there by they are no longer trees.

Comment: Right, but that takes some further reasonning to show that one part at
least is no longer a tree (actually you should split only one isolated
vertex to simplify). There is a direct proof to show at least one
vertex has degree 1. Take any vertex of non-zero degree (one must
exist). If it is degree 1, you are done. If not, start building a path
until you reach a vertex with degree one. You have to find it in n-1
step at most, because otherwise you have built a path with more than n
vertices occurrences, implying that there is a loop.

Comment: @babou Yes true. I have seen that argument as well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the definition that a tree is a simple ( meaning has no cycles) , minimally-connected graph ( meaning that removing any edge disconnects the graph.). Then use induction on the number of vertices: for $n=1$ , it is clear; try for $n=2$ , just to experiment: you have $2$ vertices and $1$ edge, and your graph is 1)acyclic -- no loops, and 2) Minimally-connected: remove any edge and you disconnect the graph. Can you do the general induction?